# DateTime reference variable is never null but throws NullPointerException

Tags: hibernate, datetime, nullpointerexception, spring-data, jodatime

I have this Entity :

```
@Entity
@Table( name = "conference" )
public class Conf implements Serializable {

  @Column( name = "start_date" )
  private DateTime                 startDate;

  @Column( name = "complete_date", unique = false, updatable = true )
  private DateTime             completeDate;

  @Column( name = "is_complet", length = 1, updatable = true, columnDefinition = "TINYINT(1)" )
  private Boolean              isComplete;

  public void setIsComplete( Boolean isComplete ) {
   System.out.println( "date is null ?" + this.completeDate == null ); //for verification
    this.isComplete = isComplete;
    this.completeDate = (this.isComplet == true && completeDate == null) ? new DateTime() : null; // null value is never assigned beccause by default completeDate seems to not be null
    this.startDate = this.completeDate != null ? new DateTime() : new DateTime( this.completeDate.getYear(), 1 + this.completeDate.getMonthOfYear(),
                    this.completeDate.getDayOfMonth(),
                    this.completeDate.getHourOfDay(),
                    this.completeDate.getMinuteOfHour() ); // this throws NPE
 }
```

The problem is in the setter method above. In fact, `completeDate` is never null even if `isComplete = true`, when I check it like this : `System.out.println( "date is null ?" + this.completeDate == null );` result `false`. But when I call any method from `completeDate`I got a NullPointerException. The strange thing is when I look a my table `conference` the `complete_date` column is null. 
Even I assign it a null value : `completeDate=null;` it changes nothing.

What is the problem? Where am I wrong? How could I solve this? Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think you have your logic backward. You print out if the date is null, and it is not. So, therefore, you are actually setting it to null, and then try to call a method on it. => NPE